# Pathfinder spell lists with properties

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Where can I find a spell list for a class (let's say druid), where not only the name and (shortened) effect is listed, but also the basic properties (range, duration, casting time, components) are listed?

I am sure something like this is out there, but the only thing I can find are lists with the names of the spells and a short description, but without any of the properties.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are probably more, but the [Spells DB](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/tools/spells-db) on the Pathfinder SRD at d20pfsrd has all that.

Pathfinder resource wise, when looking for something you should always check [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com) and [PathfinderWiki](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Wiki), they are both huge resources for rules and setting content respectively.

Answer (score 1):

For my Windows Phone 8, I use the Pathfinder Spellcards app. It has full spell text, although the search only looks at spell name and spell description, not properties.

The default alphabetical name list has spell names and available class/levels. Opening an individual spell shows all details. There are also lists by class and level, and you can create customised lists of spells for quick reference.

Answer (score 1):

On Android the [**Pathfinder Spellbook** (Chicanery games)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ChicaneryGames.PathfindersSpellbook&hl=en) gives full spell text, descriptors (range, school, saving throw etc).

You can also create favourites, list by class, and filter by School, Range, Duration, Casting Time (and other things)

I've found it very useful indeed for quickly finding spells; only thing it really is missing is a search.